# Can ctest output all log messages from the test program, e.g. boost test?

Tags: cmake, boost-test, ctest

The boost test library supports various logging options, for example: `--log_level=all` or `log_level=test_suite`.

And the `ctest` test driver program has the option `--output-on-failure` which nicely outputs the messages from *boost test*.

Is it possible to enable the above output for *passed* tests too?

Answer (score 1):

It will give a little more than what you're after, but you can add the `--verbose` flag to `ctest` and it will show the output of all tests whether they pass or fail.

Answer (score 1):

Although its an old quetion, but could help to answer it.

yes its possible to putput both failed and passed test with `-O <file>, --output-log <file>`

> -O <file>, --output-log <file>
>
> Output to log file.
> This option tells CTest to write all its output to a  log file.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html